# Playing video ads on Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to see if it's possible to play ads before/during a video on Chromecast from an Android sender.  I understand that I can handle the logic on the receiver side and switch video src to play an ad, but how would I go about pausing the controller on the sender app so that it doesn't crash when video src is changed on the receiver? I've been looking through the docs but I really can't seem to find anything on this topic.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of different options. I think the more appropriate one for your case is to have your receiver broadcast the changes on your receiver side to all the connected senders when a change happens so senders can adjust/update themselves; changes could be player status and metadata changes. For example, in a normal case, Sender A can start playback of movie A. Then while that is playing, Sender B, which is also connected, can start playing movie B. Then the Sender A will receive a media status and metadata updates informing it that the media has changes, so it can take the appropriate action, whatever it is. Your situation is not that different; handling on the sender side might be different based on your requirements.

Comment: Yes, I understand the concept behind what must be done, but my main problem is that I don't know the functions that do this.  I've been scrubbing through the chromecast api and documentation but I am not finding much that is useful. Can you give me an example / links to documents that address this? And the "appropriate action" is to pause the controller and not update itself based on the new information until the video changes back to the original content, but I can't seem to find out how to "pause" the controller

Comment: There is a fair amount of information in https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver where it discusses how you can overwrite various methods, such as onPlay, etc. Note that in your receiver, you should consider using the Media Element and the methods that are available there to play/pause/... and event there that will be fired. There are some sample on our github as well, for example you may find some useful info here: https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver

Comment: I've already done all that, but my main problem is the sender code. I don't know how to "pause" the cast controller and show a different screen while an ad is playing and resume control over the video when it goes back to the original content

Comment: You mean switching page on the sender side and pauaing on the sender?Does your sender receive the status updates from the receiver? If so, then you need to register for those messages and then do whatever you want, whether it is pause or something else. It is not clear which part you cannot do if the issue is on the sender side: the Cast related apis on the sender is done through the SDK apis and you can easily see what they are in the api reference. Outside of cast, it is just an Android app so you can do anything that you are usually able to do in an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using custom messages from the receiver to the sender to notify the sender of any status change on the receiver side with great results. Here is an example code snippet to handle various messages from the sender to the receiver -- My app is a Karaoke playlist that queues videos for playing -- it was based on CastVideoPlaylist sample app)

On the sender side, I just register a message listener to update the UI accordingly.

```
           var playlistMessageBus = castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus(
            namespace, cast.receiver.CastMessageBus.MessageType.JSON);
        // Create a message handler for the custome namespace channel
        playlistMessageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
            console.log('Playlist message: ' + JSON.stringify(event));
            // Handle the ADD command from the sender
            // Other commands could also be supported
            switch (event.data.command) {
                case 'ADD':
                    if (playlist == null) {
                        playlist = [];
                    }
                    console.log("Adding " + event.data.playlistItem.contentId + " to playlist");
                    playlist.push(event.data.playlistItem);
                    break;
                case 'DELETE':
                    // delete the selected item from playlist
                    {
                    var code = 0;
                    if (playlist == null) {
                        code = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        // find the listItem title, then delete it
                        var index;
                        for (index = 0; index < playlist.length; index++) {
                            if (playlist[index].title == event.data.playlistItem.title) {
                            console.log('Found ' + event.data.playlistItem.title + 'in playlist');
                            break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (index < playlist.length) {
                            playlist.splice(index,1);
                            code = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    var message = {
                        commandResult: 'CMD_RESULT',
                        responseCode: code 
                        };
                    playlistMessageBus.send(event.senderId, JSON.stringify(message));
                    }
                    break;
                case 'MOVE_TOP':
                    {
                    // move the selected listItem to top of the playlist
                    var code = 0;
                    if (playlist == null) {
                        code = 0;
                    }
                    else if (playlist.length == 1) {
                        code = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        // find the listItem title, then move it to the top
                        var index;
                        for (index = 0; index < playlist.length; index++) {
                            if (playlist[index].title == event.data.playlistItem.title) {
                                console.log('Found ' + event.data.playlistItem.title + 'in playlist');
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (index < playlist.length) {
                            playlist.splice(index,1);
                            playlist.unshift(event.data.playlistItem);
                            code = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    var message = {
                        commandResult: 'CMD_RESULT',
                        responseCode: code
                        };
                    playlistMessageBus.send(event.senderId, JSON.stringify(message));
                    }
                    break;
                case 'QUERY':
                    switch (event.data.category) {
                        case 'PLAY_STATUS':
                            {
                            console.log("Sending play status back to sender app");
                            // inform all senders on the CastMessageBus of the incoming message event
                            // sender message listener will be invoked
                            var playState = (inPlay) ? 'PLAYING' : 'STOPPED';
                            var message = {
                                playstatus: 'PLAY_STATUS',
                                state: playState
                                };
                            playlistMessageBus.send(event.senderId, JSON.stringify(message));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'SELECTED_MEDIA':
                            {
                            // return the current select media
                            var listItem = null;
                            if (curLoadedPlaylistItem != null) {
                                listItem = {
                                    title: curLoadedPlaylistItem.title,
                                    contentId : curLoadedPlaylistItem.contentID,
                                    image: curLoadedPlaylistItem.image
                                    };
                            }
                            var message = {
                                mediastatus: 'MEDIA_STATUS',
                                playlistItem: listItem
                                };
                            playlistMessageBus.send(event.senderId, JSON.stringify(message));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'PLAYLIST':
                            {
                            // return the playlist
                            var message = {
                                playliststatus: 'PLAYLIST',
                                playlist: playlist
                                };
                            playlistMessageBus.send(event.senderId, JSON.stringify(message));
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.log("Unrecognized category from sender: " + event.data.category);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Unrecognized command from sender: " + event.data.command);
                    break;
            }
        };
```